# jQuery: select "this" child elements

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I'm really going crazy of this particular obstacle, the issue in hand is that I have a very simple table with rows and all. what I'm trying to accomplish is that when you click on a row then this script is suppose to read the link that's stored in the last `td` in the very same row and then direct you there.

What I've come up with so far is this

```
 $('tr td').click(
     function (){
        alert($(this+':parent td:last-child a:first').attr('href'));
     }
 );
```

I've tried 100 of different approaches I either get an error/undefined or I only get the result of the last/first row the rows in-between doesn't work as supposed to.

All help is really appreciated

table looked as following

http://www.jsfiddle.net/xK7Mg/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
$('tr td').click(function() {
   window.location.href = $(this).parent().find('td:last-child a:first').attr('href');
});
```

Comment: this worked but It wasn't the linking that was problem, i just alerted to see if it got the right value ;) thought that it was obvious =P

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) in this case, though `.parent().children()` also works, like this:

```
$('tr td').click(function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).siblings('td:last').find('a').attr('href');
});
```

Take it one step further though, don't attach a `click` handler to every cell, use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach one for the entire table, like this:

```
$('#tableID').delegate('td', 'click', function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).siblings('td:last').find('a').attr('href');
});
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yruTZ/1/).

Comment: no doesn't work still only returns the link from the first row

Comment: @Breezer - That shouldn't be the case at all, what does your markup look like?

Comment: @Breezer - updated to the correct selector, *please* use `.delegate()` for this, it's much, *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this I think:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find('td:last a:first').attr('href');
});
```

This script will cause each table row, when clicked, redirect you to the location referenced in the first anchor element in the last table cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').click(
     function (){
        window.location = $(this).find("td:last a:first").attr('href');
     }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ppw8z/

```
 $('tr').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find('td>a').attr('href');    
 });
```

Comment: This would get the first `<a>` in the row, in *any* cell.

Comment: Yea, I made the assumption there was only 1 link in the last TD.  Possibly not the case.